# How to fetch a class from a variable with generic types

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a variable such as

```
Function<T, String> myFn;
```

I want to use it to get the class of type T.

For example, if we have

```
Function<Integer, String> myFn;
```

I need to get Integer.class.

I know that if we have

```
Integer x;
```

We can get Integer.class using x.getClass()

**EDIT:** Can we do this without using reflection?

**EDIT:** A more complete example

```
class MyFnClass<T> {
    Function<T, String> myFn;
    ...
    public Class<T> getTypeClass() {
       ???
    }
}
```

Note that it doesn't have to use myFn, but since we cannot do T.class or something, I thought myFn is the only way to get this. Solutions that don't use myFn in this case are also acceptable.

Comment: Is this variable a field within a generic type? There's a big difference between `Function<T, String>` in a generic type, and `Function<Integer, String>` in a non-generic type. A short but *complete* example would really help here. (What you're asking for may be possible, but it may not...)

Comment: And note that you can only get `Integer.class` from `x.getClass()` if the value of `x` is non-null.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I can safely assume that the instance variable is non-null

Comment: @user34812 do check my solution that should help

Comment: @VivekSingh: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the solution shouldn't use reflection. Edited the question now

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) meaning that the type information related to generics is removed at compile time.

It is therefore not possible to get the type `T` from `Function<T, String>` at runtime.

In the code snippet you include, you can could do this:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunction<T> 
{
  private Function<T, String> function;

  ...

  public Class<T> getInputType() throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    return (Class<T>)Class.forName(((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName());
  }
}

public IntegerFunction extends AbstractFunction<Integer>
{
}
```

While all very *tricksy*, it is imho unnecessarily complex and can reduced to:

```
public abstract class AbstractFunction<T> 
{
  private Function<T, String> function;

  ...

  public abstract Class<T> getInputType();
}

public IntegerFunction extends AbstractFunction<Integer>
{
  @Override
  public Class<Integer> getInputType()
  {
    return Integer.class;
  }
}
```

This still introduces a rather pointless class, which can be reduced further to:

```
public class MyFunction<T> 
{
  private Class<T> inputType;
  private Function<T, String> function;

  public MyFunction(Class<T> inputType, Function<T, String> function)
  {
    this.inputType = inputType;
    this.function = function;
  }

  public Class<T> getInputType()
  {
    return inputType;
  }
}
```

All that said, needing to know the generic type is a bit of a [code-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and may indicated that there's something else not quite right in your design.

Comment: It's only possible if you can somehow obtain an object of type `T`, then you can do `thatObj.getClass()`. It might still be a subtype of T or an anonymous class, though, unless the used class for `T` is final. (`Integer` is final.) It's good to declare `T` as `T extends Number` or something, to at least know the upper bound (range of classes) of what T can be.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can access the class from a variable like this:

    myLocalVar = myClass.getMyVarVal();

Please refer this case as below :

public class myClass<T> {

    protected Class<T> clazz;

    public myClass() {
        this.clazz = (Class<>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public Class<T> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

public class Fetch extends myClass<C> {
   /* ... */
    public void fetchClassFromVariable() {
       //here we can call getClazz() to get the class from variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. I don't know what any of these identifiers stand for.

Comment: The you need to learn the basics of oops and java first before commenting here.